# How can I use @AutoFactory with an @AutoValue class?

Tags: java, auto-value, autofactory

Say I have a simple AutoValue class:

```
@AutoValue abstract class Foo {
  abstract CommonDependency commonDep();
  abstract String uniqueDataPerInstance();

  static Foo create(CommonDependency commonDep, String data) {
    return new AutoValue_Foo(commonDep, data);
  }
}
```

Now I want a factory so I don't need to pass commonDep each time I want a Foo. If this were not an AutoValue class, I could use AutoFactory for this trivially by annotating CommonDependency `@Provided`.

Do you know of a way to make these two code generators work well together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is indeed a quite interesting problem, since the `@AutoFactory` annotation can only be applied to non-abstract classes.

> error: Auto-factory doesn't support being applied to abstract classes.

For annotated constructors there was not even a useful error message after the compiler had failed.

Since there are only `abstract` or `final` auto-value classes in the code generation process, we'd have to annotate the last and final class. To do this you'd have to implement an auto-value extension, which `mustBeFinal()` and annotates the class declaration or the constructor of the final class with the `@AutoFactory` annotation.

Here's another issue taking effect, because the constructor parameters need to be annotated appropriately. So `@Provided`, `@Nullable` or any `@Qualifier` annotation need to be added there. The biggest issue here is, that `@Provided` defines `@Target(PARAMETER)` and with auto-value we only define methods.

If you don't want to implement it yourself, you could try to use [`auto-value-factory`](https://github.com/tynn/auto-value-factory). I implemented it in the process to see, how both auto-libraries work together.